# How to rename a file while downloading from a website using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, browser, cross-browser, content-security-policy

I have a web page which contains link to another website in different domain say "example.com\abc.msi". when I click on the link, the file starts downloading but I need to rename this file while downloading from that website. How can I accomplish this? I tried using download attribute of anchor tag, but for some reason its not working. This needs to be done in client side. Please help!

Comment: The download attribute only works with certain browsers. See [list](http://caniuse.com/#feat=download). I don't think it's possible to use Javascript to rename the downloaded file.

Comment: Yes, it only works with certain browsers. Chrome supports it, but I am unable to rename the file.

Comment: Does your page include the HTML5 doctype like the [W3Schools example](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_a_download) that you reference? It may not work correctly without it.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change the name of the file to be downloaded for it would be a security issue. You can imagine clicking a file `image.png`, and getting `image.png.exe` instead. This is not something browser developers would alow.

Comment: please take a look in this site. Through program we can rename a file. "w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_a_download"

Comment: The downloaded file name is exactly the last part of the link in a href attribute: myw3schoolsimage.jpg. That is how it is supposed to work. And you cannot change this name without changing the link.

Answer (score 0):

your abc.msi is a ftp file so whenever anyone call to the file or click on the link it will either be automatically downloaded or open a dialog for saving file on location

for example

[image]

hence it's up to the user where and how he wants to save the file.

Comment: please take a look in this site. Through program we can rename a file. "http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_a_download"

Comment: the link is broken. please provide a proper URL

Comment: @Chetan Naik - The correct link is [example](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_a_download)